# How to show an object provided as an argument by a user on a UML class diagram?

Tags: javascript, constructor, uml, class-diagram

I have a JavaScript function, which is supposed to act like a class, and it needs several pieces of data from a user.

I decided to make it to expect one single object with those data pieces as its arguments, like:

```
new ClassFunction({
  arg_1: 'foo',
  arg_2: 'bar'
});
```

What is the best way to show this on a UML class diagram?

Should I write it as a comment in the curly braces or as a separate note or as an abstract class with a dependency line from the constructor class (ClassFunction) to that abstract class?

Or may be something else?

Comment: Can you model that object as a datatype and use the datatype as an argument to the function?

Comment: @Jim L. thanks, this is what I wanted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> JavaScript function, which is supposed to act like a class

The more proper term would be *object constructor*; this may also give you a better idea of what you are actually trying to do.

Now the parameter provided to the constructor is some anonymous class that understands `arg_1` and `arg_2`. UML models this via `DataType`s, denoted with the `<<dataType>>` keyword.

> A DataType is a kind of Classifier. DataType differs from Class in that instances of a DataType are identified only by their value. All instances of a DataType with the same value are considered to be equal instances. [UML Spec 10.2]

So for example your case could be modeled as the following:

[image]